# How to remove repetition of data in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 Application using Existing SQLite Database.Now I'm able to make a connection and fetch out the appropriate data. But the data i'm getting in form of repeatation. How can i resolve that?

Here is my Code Snippet

```
  private void Filter_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TaskListBox.Items.Clear();
        SQLiteCommand sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand(dbConn);
     sqlComm.CommandText = "Select * from TABLE_OLIST where OP_DESC=" + TitleField.Text;
        List<MergIsd_List> retrievedTasks = sqlComm.ExecuteQuery<MergIsd_List>();
        foreach (var t in retrievedTasks)
        {
            TaskListBox.Items.Add(t);
        }

    }
   public class MergIsd_List
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
       public int _id { get; set; }
    public string OP_NAME { get; set; }
    public string OP_DESC { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
          return OP_NAME + OP_DESC;

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `But the data i'm getting in form of repeatation.` mean exactly?

Comment: Thankx @Jens This Means that the data i deserve in single line i get the same in four lines.. means data repeatation

Comment: Use Distinct like this Select distinct * from TABLE ...............

Comment: Possible reason I can think of for duplicates is not clearing `TaskListBox`, try clearing TaskListBox before adding items.

Comment: Thankx @HariPrasad I'm using TaskListBox.Items.Clear(); in the Filter Click.. But still problem is same

Comment: @RituTyagi then try to use `retrievedTasks.Distinct()` in your `foreach` statement.

Comment: Thanku So Much :) @HariPrasad  I appreciate issue get  Resolved..

Comment: Preferably use the same Distinct in the SQL Query not after fetching that in memory, it will be inefficient, especially for a mobile, bring as less data as possible from source itself

Comment: Okay @MrinalKamboj Thanku for your Suggestion :)